# Failed with error: deadline 2020-05-12T09:41:54.343 exceeded by 73us

Tags: nodeos, eosio.cdt, eosio.system

I am trying this to set **eosio.system** smart-contract using this command:

> cleos set contract eosio
>   /home/varshakhandre14/contracts/newcontract/eosio.contracts/build/contracts/eosio.system/

I am following the BIOS boot sequence tutorial. Getting following error:

> Reading WASM from
>   /home/varshakhandre14/contracts/newcontract/eosio.contracts/build/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.wasm...
>   Publishing contract... error 2020-05-12T09:41:54.346 cleos
>   main.cpp:4013                 main                 ] Failed with
>   error: deadline 2020-05-12T09:41:54.343 exceeded by 73us  (2) deadline
>   2020-05-12T09:41:54.343 exceeded by 73us

I search for the solution and found that I need to increase transaction execution time. So I add

> --max-transaction-time=1000
>   in *config.ini*.
>   Still, I am getting the same issue. Any alternate solution?

Comment: retry, retry, and retry

Comment: Yes, but sometimes it is irritating. When I wrote the script, I had to put this command in the `for` loop.